# MUL gets runtime error when using GCC asm

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I want to calculate `x * y % 998244353` by GCC asm, so I wrote the asm code :

```
int Modmul(int x, int y)
{
    int t;

    __asm__ __volatile__ ("mull %%ebx\n\tdivl %%ecx\n\t" : "=d"(t) : "a"(x), "b"(y), "c"(998244353) : "eax", "edx", "memory");

    return t;
}
```

However, it got compile error "'asm' operand has impossible constraints', and if I remove `: "eax", "edx", "memory"`, it can pass the compilation but got the wrong answer, why?

BTW, I replaced `ebx` with `r0` and `ecx` with `r1`:

```
int Modmul(int x, int y)
{
    int t;

    __asm__ __volatile__ ("mull %0\n\tdivl %1\n\t" : "=d"(t) : "a"(x), "r"(y), "r"(998244353));

    return t;
}
```

It can pass the compilation, but it got runtime error, why?

Comment: The first code snippet could have been written as `int Modmul(int x, int y)
{
    int t;

    __asm__ \
        ("mull %%ebx\n\tdivl %%ecx\n\t"
        : "=d"(t), "+a"(x)
        : "b"(y), "c"(998244353));

    return t;
}` . `memory` clobber isn't needed because you don't touch memory. You can't use  `eax` as a clobber because you have it as an input operand. You can mark `eax` as input/output to fix that. volatile isn't needed because there are no side effects other than the outputs that are full defined in the constraints.

Comment: Why not just write this code in C?

Comment: Be aware that `mul` is unsigned multiply, but your inputs are signed. What is an example of inputs that yield the wrong result (show an example of a value of x and y where the return value is wrong and what the expected value should have been)

Comment: Be aware that DIV on x86 has a latency of 29, whereas MUL just 4. It's possible to compute "x * y % 998244353" without DIV. So your hand-made assembly can be made faster (which is what would happen if you let the compiler do the work).

Comment: The second code snippet won't work because you don't use EAX as an input. The way you have done the MUL/DIV only allows for the parameters `y` and `998244353` to be passed in compiler chosen registers using an `r` constraint.

Comment: @JL2210 . Worth noting : The issue with using EBX with position independent code and impossible constraints was fixed in either v5 or v6 of GCC (don't recall which ff the top of my head). The fix was to save and restore EBX if inline assembly required its usage in a constraint.

Comment: @JL2210 That doesn't matter anymore with modern gcc.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Because GCC doesn't know how to optimize `uint64_t / uint32_t` into a single `div` instruction; it doesn't even try to prove that the divisor is large enough that the quotient can't overflow and fault with #DE.  Of course in this case, you'd need to use something like `if(x * y>something) __builtin_unreachable()` to promise that it's safe because it's *not* provably safe.

Comment: @PeterCordes : If he was going for optimizations then he wouldn't be using `div` to compute the remainder. There are faster ways to do it. Which begs the question - what was the intention with the inline assembly in the first place.

Comment: @rustyx: IIRC, gcc doesn't use a multiplicative inverse for uint64/uint32 on a 32-bit machine.  So you would actually get a `div` instruction in your output, with extra branching in a GCC helper function that does uint64/uint64 to check the size of the inputs and see if it can use 1 or 2 instead of 3 `div` instructions.  But yes the best bet might still be 64 x 64 => 128-bit multiplication using 32x32=>64-bit mul (assuming this is 32-bit code).  It's clear the OP's asm is using the 64-bit full result of `x*y` in EDX:EAX, so I presume the actual source they want to implement is `x*(uint64_t)y`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am really optimizing it. How to calculate the remainder without `div`? BTW, the second code block in the question was written incorrect, I fixed it but it still gets runtime error now.

Comment: What version of GCC is it (`gcc -v` should give a version number. What is the command line you use to compile the file? And can you update the question with an example `main` with a call to `Modmul` using parameters that you get the wrong value returned at run-time? I'd like to see an example of what are the inputs to Modmul and what the return value is that is wrong.

Comment: The revised second snippet where you have `mull %0\n\tdivl %1\n\t` is wrong because %0 and %1 are the constraints for `t` and `x` but I think you want to use %2 and %3 for `y` and `c`

Comment: @MichaelPetch `gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`. It only gots wrong when I did millions of tests of it. I think it will be hard to construct a single test but I will try.

Comment: If you run all the tests (a lot of them) are you always using the same values for X and Y and the result comes up wrong occasionally? Or do you try different values of X and Y in all the tests and then compare it to the results of a routine that is working?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads in the real program simultaneously? Or is it just one thread of execution (a single main program without threads)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I did not use multiple threads. It gots wrong in a single thread real program, so the X and Y are different but is guaranteed that `0 <= x, y < 998244353` .

Comment: Try this. Using this version I mentioned in my earlier comment `int Modmul(int x, int y) { int t; __asm__  ("mull %%ebx\n\tdivl %%ecx\n\t" : "=d"(t), "+a"(x) : "b"(y), "c"(998244353)); return t; }` . Use that and call it with `Modmul (0xffffffff, 0xffffffff)` - does it fail with a runtime error of some sort? If so what error? My best guess is that when it fails the 64-bit value in edx:eax prior to the divl when divided by `998244353` is too large to be represented in 32-bits and you are getting some type of run-time exception (some kind of arithmetic error).

Comment: @MichaelPetch This version works correctly, thanks. BTW, you mentioned that 'There are faster ways to do it', how?

Comment: @Ghastlcon so your target is actually x64? In that case you can use 64-bit regs and compute the result with 3 MULs and 0 DIVs. See [this example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6yE8fc)